# Kotlin: How can i access the the LayoutInflater from a function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've a fragment with a `recyclerview`, i need to fill the `RecyclerView` from a function, but i don't know how to access to the `recyclerView` from the function, this is my code :

```
class ValcuotaDataFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valcuota_data, container, false)

    return root
}
@Subscribe
fun listenItemChange(spinnerData: SpinnerData){   }
```

i need to do this :

```
        val rcView= root.findViewById(R.id.rcViewName) as RecyclerView
```

from the function `listenItemChange`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you return from `onCreateView()` can be later retrieved with `getView()`. So you're looking for something like `view?.findViewById(...)`.

Be cautious with fragment lifecycle so you're only trying to use `getView()` between `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()`. (It will return null otherwise.)